# Nested herodoc order of operations

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code -

```
ssh host sh -s << EOF
cd /backup/

ls

psql -U user -d db << SQL
$(sed 's/${previous_quarter}/${current_quarter}/' table_quarters.sql);
$(sed 's/${previous_quarter}/${current_quarter}/' plans.sql);
SQL

EOF
```

This is the order of execution it is following when I execute it -

1. `table_quarters` script
2. `plans` script
3. `ls` command.

Why is it not following this order of execution -

1. `ls` command
2. `table_quarters` script
3. `plans` script

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a string to the standard input of `ssh`. This string can only be constructed if the stuff in `$(...)` is run first, because these parts will be replaced by the output of the enclosed commands.

Once the string is expanded, it's send by ssh to the remote machine which runs the resulting commands in order.

If you want to run the expansions on the remote end, you need to properly escape the dollar signs.

Comment: Note that "properly escap[ing] the dollar signs" can be almost trivially done with `ssh host sh -s << 'EOF'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Unless you want some variables to expand locally...